# There are two node_modules directories on my computer. How can I configure npm to install libraries in the global path?

Tags: node.js, npm, appium, node-modules, appium-ios

I am trying to follow this Appium tutorial: [Appium XCUITest Driver Real Device Setup (Full manual configuration)](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/#full-manual-configuration)
When attempting to find the path of **appium-webdriveragent**
I found out that there are two node_modules directories on my computer.

1. `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/`
2. `/users/myuser/node_modules`

When I run `npm root -g` I get this output `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

When I attempt to install **appium-webdriveragent** I realized that the file is installed in the directory `/users/myuser/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent`

How can I configure npm to install libraries in the first path?
What can I do to install the **appium-webdriveragent** in the first directory? like below.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
```

Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: According to that tutorial, appium-webdriveragent should be already there after appium is installed. How did you install appium?

Comment: Hi and thank you,
I think I installed Appium via npm,  in this case appium-webdriveragent was not already in this directory / usr / local / lib / node_modules / appium / node_modules /

Comment: If you really want to install it there, `cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium`, then `sudo npm i appium-webdriveragent`, but I have a feeling that something is fishy with your installation